# Relation between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, rational-numbers, vector-space-isomorphism, quotient-set

Is there a way of writing $\mathbb{Q}$ in terms of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in a simple expression?

My idea is to construct $\mathbb{Q}$ a quotient set of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers. To form $\mathbb{Q}$, we could start with the Cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\})$ which is the set of all ordered pairs $(p, q)$ such that $p$ is an integer and $q$ is a non-zero integer. These pairs would correspond to the fractions $p/q$.

However, this set contains redundancies because the same rational number can be represented in different ways (for example, $1/2$ is the same as $2/4$). To obtain a set that corresponds exactly to the rational numbers, we could identify pairs $(p, q)$ and $(p', q')$ if they represent the same rational number. This is the same as saying that $(p, q)$ and $(p', q')$ are identified if $pq' = p'q$.

The result would then be a quotient set $(\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}))/\text{~}$, where ~ is the equivalence relation defined by $(p, q) \text{~} (p', q')$ if and only if $pq' = p'q$. This quotient set is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers.

Is this the best way to do it? It is not written explicitly in terms of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, I had to somehow deconstruct it, but I wonder if there is a better way to write it. From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928631/is-mathbbq-isomorphic-to-mathbbz2), for example, we see that $\mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Z^2} $ can be ambiguous.

Comment: Until you provide a  definition of "best way to do it" this standard construction is surely very good. It's easy to understand and leads easily to all the properties you want in the rationals.

Comment: @samwolfe $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is not a vector space so it is not clear what you mean by "highlighting the parallelism between both vector spaces"

Comment: @samwolfe That's the thing. The integers are **not** a field.

Comment: @EthanBolker I am simply requesting a shorter version of what I wrote, possibly involving an expression with $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Apologies also for the previous reply, it was wrong and misleading, as user 0XLR pointed out. I deleted it to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @samwolfe This is the key to your question. If you can be precise about exactly what type of structures we should view $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z^2$ as, then you can be precise about "highlighting the parallelism" between them. E.g. if you just view them as amorphous sets then any bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z^2$ is the simplest relation between them that "highlights that fact" so to speak

Comment: @0XLR Good point. I am not too familiar with the idea of an amorphous set, but I can look it up and get some clarity.

Comment: As discussed at the post you linked in your last sentence, there is structure associated with $\Bbb Q$ (in particular the addition and multiplication operations, which make it a field) that should be defined as part of "constructing" $\Bbb Q$. Without arithmetic operations, $\Bbb Q$ is just any old countable set.

Comment: @Karl I see. Perhaps it then suffices to say $\mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Z^2} $ (as sets) to highlight that, from a category theory perspective. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, but it sounds like a bijection $\Bbb Z^2\to\Bbb Q$ is not what you're looking for.

Comment: If you just want to construct the set of pairs of integers $(a,b)$ found in canonical reduced fractions $\frac ab$, you can do something like $\{(a,b)\in\Bbb Z^2:b>0,\gcd(a,b)=1\}.$